# Проверить равен ли введенный текст атрибуту поля ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю тест, хочу что бы при введении правильного ответа подчеркивалось поле ввода, но получается только с единичным полем. Как сделать так что бы не надо было мой код дублировать для каждого поля? Ибо их у меня десятки будут.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='answer[1]']").keyup(function() {
        if (this.value == $(this).data("answer")) {
            $("input[name='answer[1]").addClass('good');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.good {
border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="questions">
<li>Hva <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="" data-answer="heter" /> du?</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="" data-answer="Bor"/> du i Litauen?</li>
<li>Kommer <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="" data-answer="du"/>på jobb i dag?</li>
<li>Hun <input type="text" name="answer[4]" value="" data-answer="heter"/>Siri.</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[5]" value="" data-answer="han"/>heter Tomas.</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer[6]" value="" data-answer="Er"/>dere fra Frankrike?</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.questions').find('input').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value === $(this).data('answer')) {
      $(this).addClass('good');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('good');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.good {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="questions">
  <li>Hva <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="" data-answer="heter" /> du?</li>
  <li><input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="" data-answer="Bor"/> du i Litauen?</li>
  <li>Kommer <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="" data-answer="du"/>på jobb i dag?</li>
  <li>Hun <input type="text" name="answer[4]" value="" data-answer="heter"/>Siri.</li>
  <li><input type="text" name="answer[5]" value="" data-answer="han"/>heter Tomas.</li>
  <li><input type="text" name="answer[6]" value="" data-answer="Er"/>dere fra Frankrike?</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: оказывается все было так просто... а я про какие то циклы думал ))) спасибо!